# A simple property of the norm of an cyclotomic integer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number and $\zeta$ be a primitive $l$-th  root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ be the cyclotomic field.
Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
Let $\alpha \in A$. 
Let $N(\alpha)$ be the norm of $\alpha$.

My question: How can we prove that $N(\alpha) \equiv 0$ or $\equiv 1$ (mod $l$)?

Comment: Is $A = \Bbb{Z}[\zeta_l]$ where $l$ is the odd prime in the assumption?

Comment: @BenjaLim It's a well known fact. So you can take it for granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\zeta^n-\zeta\in (1-\zeta)$ if $l$ does not divide $n$. This implies that all the conjugates of $\alpha$ are congruent mod $(1-\zeta)$, hence $N\alpha\equiv \alpha^{l-1}$ mod $(1-\zeta)$. Since $A/(1-\zeta)\cong\mathbb{F}_l$, we have $N\alpha\equiv0$ or $\equiv1$ mod $l$.

Comment: I'd like to add a bit of explanation just in case.
Since $\zeta \equiv 1$ (mod $1 - \zeta$), $\zeta^n \equiv 1$ (mod $1 - \zeta$). Hence $\zeta \equiv \zeta^n$ (mod $1 - \zeta$).